# Can R create a matrix and at the same time process the created columns to form a new one?

Tags: r, matrix, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a new matrix from an existing one. Specifically, I want to subtract column `A2` from column `A1`, `A4` from `A3` and `A6` from `A5` as in the example, but at the same time i want to create a new column that is the row mean of these results:

```
A <- matrix(c(2,3,-2,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),3,6)
dimnames(A) <- list(c("a","b","c"), c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6"))

B <- data.frame(minus12=A[, c("A1")]-A[, c("A2")], 
    minus34=A[, c("A3")]-A[, c("A4")], 
    minus56=A[, c("A5")]-A[, c("A6")],  
    mean=rowMeans(B[c("minus12","minus34","minus56")]))
```

I tried the above and it worked with such a small matrix. But with my actual data, which is a much bigger matrix A and matrix B has other operations calculated while it is created (means of rows from matrix A), this doesn't work. Instead, I get this message:

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'B' not found

I checked and didn't find anything different with the above, working, code. What could be the problem? How do I make this happen with a bigger, more complicated matrix?

Answer (score 2):

We can use the logical recycling to subtract the odd/even columns, then `cbind` with the original dataset to `rowMeans` of the output.

```
 val <- A[,c(TRUE, FALSE)]-A[, c(FALSE, TRUE)]
 colnames(val) <- paste0('minus', seq(1, ncol(A), by=2), 
                 seq(2,ncol(A), by =2))
 Anew <- cbind(val, Mean=rowMeans(val))
 Anew
 #  minus12 minus34 minus56      Mean
 #a       1      -3      -3 -1.666667
 #b       1      -3      -3 -1.666667
 #c      -4      -3      -3 -3.333333
```

Comment: I think (I am new to R so I am not sure) that I need to do this through the data.frame order, because i want to have multiple calculated columns and name them at the same time. This won't let me do that, I think.

Comment: @athinoutsi The code is based on the code you showed on your post.  I am not sure whether you tried the code or not.  The column names of the `val` can be changed using `colnames(val) <- paste0('minus', seq(1, ncol(A), by=2), seq(2,ncol(A), by =2))`